# confusion about conversion answer infix to postfix

Tags: data-structures, postfix-notation

I am trying to learn about Infix to Postfix Conversion from the internet 
I have come across 2 sources following which I get different answers to the same infix expression:

a/b^c+d*e/f-g+h

I am wondering which algorithm is correct

source 1 : https://youtu.be/IAxCAbcqQFA?t=803 as you can see here the answer is

abc^/de*+f/g-h+

source 2 : https://raj457036.github.io/Simple-Tools/prefixAndPostfixConvertor.html

answer is

abc^/de*+f/gh+-

Comment: also for the infix expression a+b-(c*d)/e^(f-g)^h the answer from the calculator is  ab+cd*efg-h^^/-  how ever the answer by following the video's algorithm is ab+cd*efg-^h^/-

Comment: i think both are right

Comment: They're both wrong. `a/b^c+d*e/f-g+h` should be evaluated as `(a/(b^c)+(d*e/f))-g+h`. Both examples above are doing `(a/(b^c)+(d*e)/f)-g+h`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm.

Comment: Actually, the first source appears correct. You made an error copying the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the output, you can evaluate the expression yourself.  Just open an editor and use a line as a stack:

Answer 1: abc^/de*+f/g-h+

```
a:  a
b:  a  b
c:  a  b  c
^:  a  b^c
/:  a/b^c
d:  a/b^c  d
e:  a/b^c  d  e
*:  a/b^c  d*e
+:  a/b^c+d*e
f:  a/b^c+d*e  f
/:  (a/b^c+d*e)/f
g:  (a/b^c+d*e)/f  g
-:  (a/b^c+d*e)/f-g
h:  (a/b^c+d*e)/f-g  h
+:  (a/b^c+d*e)/f-g+h
```

Looks like that one's wrong.

You can do the second one yourself.  It's also wrong.

Conversion from infix to postfix is also easy to do manually.  You just do the operators in the proper order, changing `arg op arg op arg...` to `arg arg op arg op...`  Here I use `[]` to hold the already-converted subexpressions:

```
a/b^c+d*e/f-g+h
a/[bc^]+d*e/f-g+h
[abc^/]+[de*f/]-g+h
[abc^/de*f/+g-h+]
```